# Webpack hangs at build stage

Tags: babeljs, webpack-5

I recently did a fairly big merge, after it Webpack just hangs at 52% in building the modules.

```
[52%] building (457/1296 modules)
```

When setting the debug flag `DEBUG=*` I see the following last Babel log:

```
  babel program.body[6] ExportDefaultDeclaration: Recursing into... +0ms
```

I did the whole merge already twice since I thought maybe I made a mistake, tho I ended up with the same issue.

No project dependency was added, just the source code has been changed.

Any help is greatly appreciated as I don't find any resources on how to debug such a freeze.

Answer (score 0):

After a long night of fiddling around it turned out that the issue was `dart-sass` in combination with its `url-encode` function.

Even tho we use it a few times in our App at one specific case it won't work. I fixed it by simple uri-encode the string already manually, so SASS doesn't have to do it.